# How to fetch from two databases in a single request in koajs using pg.pool

Tags: node.js, node-postgres, koa2

I am trying to get a combined result from two tables of different databases.I am new to koajs and Node.js.
Below is my sample code what I am trying:

db/index.js

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')

const pool = new Pool({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: '5432',
  user: 'postgres',
  password: 'postgres',
  database: 'sampl',
  max: 20,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
  connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000,
});

const pool1 = new Pool({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: '5432',
  user: 'postgres',
  password: 'postgres',
  database: 'secon',
  max: 20,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
  connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000,
});
```

My route file [/route.js] here I use

```
import Router from 'koa-router'
const router = new Router()
var someVar = [];
var internas = [];
const db = require('../db')
router.get('/samson', ctx => {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM sam', null, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < res.rowCount; i++) {
      var sno = res.rows[i].sno;
      var name = res.rows[i].name;
      var mobile = res.rows[i].mobile;
      var indx = i + 1;
      internas[i] = setValue(res.rows[i], i);
      console.log(internas);
      db.squery('SELECT * FROM dtl where sno=$1', [sno], (err, resu) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          var salary = resu.rows[0].salary;
          var address = resu.rows[0].address;
          console.log(someVar);
        }
      })
    }
  })
  ctx.body = internas;
})

function setValue(value, index) {
  var someVars = value;
  return someVars;
}
export default router
```

I am trying to combine two tables from two databases for a single request

```
Table 1 contain: sno, name, mobile
Table 2 contain: sno, salary, address
```

My expectation is for every record in table 1 I need to fetch from table 2
and output will be like

```
Record1: sno, name, mobile, salary, address
record2: sno, name, mobile, salary, address
```

Please suggest, I used to synchronous programming and this is asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

You could use pg-promise instead, and use async/await and make your life a little easier, and tasks to make it more performant.

```
const { Pool } = require('pg-promise')

router.get('/samson', async ctx => {
  try{
    db.task('my-es7-task', async t => {
      let res = await t.any('SELECT * FROM sam', null);
      for (var i = 0; i < res.rowCount; i++) {
        try{
          var sno = res.rows[i].sno;
          var name = res.rows[i].name;
          var mobile = res.rows[i].mobile;
          var indx = i + 1;
          internas[i] = setValue(res.rows[i], i);
          console.log(internas);
          let results = await t.any('SELECT * FROM dtl where sno=$1', [sno])
          var salary = resu.rows[0].salary;
          var address = resu.rows[0].address;
          console.log(someVar);
        }catch(e){
          console.log(e);
        }
      }
      ctx.body = internas;
    }
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
})
```

Comment: Except, one should use a task for it, see [Chaining Queries](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Chaining-Queries). And, `pg-promise` doesn't export any `Pool` object.

Comment: Updated, hopefully correct! (Since I'm not familiar with Chaining queries)

Comment: Not the best example in how to loop through data, but it will work with tasks. As for the second part - `pg-promise` doesn't export any `Pool` object, it is still incorrect.